# Can not connect to BLE device on raspberry pi (gatttool/bluetoothctl)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, bluez, gatttool

like the title says, i am not able to connect to a le device on my raspberry pi 3. 
I tried:
- via bluetoothctl i get an AutenthicationFailure 
- via gatttool i get connection refused (111)

I searched a lot for a solution and already tried (made sure that):
- btmgmt le up
- reinstalling bluez/bluez to the newest version
- use of "-t random" when using gatttool

And know i really have no idea what to do next.

What might be important:
uname -r =  4.19.58-v7+
bluetoothctl -v = 5.50
Using the Android App nRF Connect the connection to the le device works fine.

Can somebody help me please?

Thanks in advance,
Magda

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your device needs to be bonded and Bluez fails to successfully bond...

I have the same issue with several devices that need bonding. Bluez can apparently only deal with some variants of bonding but certainly not all. On iOS and Android I have no issues at all with those devices...

Unless you fancy digging into Bluez source code and fixing the issue yourself, I think you can only wait for some Bluez update to fix the issue...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When connecting with my android via app, there actually was no bonding needed. So I was able to connect without bonding before. So if it's like you said, it also had to fail with my android, right? Or are there possibilities where its a difference?

Comment: If your device uses JustWorks bonding then you won't notice anything on Android either. But since you get the error AutenthicationFailure it clearly tries to do some form of bonding.

Comment: Any updates on this issue..? Did it work eventually..?